# difference between erase and remove/remove_if algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl

What is really the difference between the algorithms remove and remove_if and the member function erase? 
*Does* both of them result in a call to the removed objects destructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `std::remove_if` will move the elements that don't match the predicate to the end of list and will return an iterator to the new "end". Erase will effectively drop the element (call the dtor) from the container.

The difference is perfectly illustrated by the examples [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/).

Comment: `remove` and `remove_if` do not need to move the "removed" items to the end of the list.  The only guarantee is that those items between begin and the returned, new, end are the items that passed the test.  After that could be anything.  (See Meyer's Effective STL for an example.)

Answer (score 11):

No, `remove` and `remove_if` only move objects around in the sequence. You need to call erase to make the sequence actually shorter. The return value of remove and remove_if is the iterator you can use in an `erase` call to shorten the sequence:

```
sequence.erase(remove(...),sequence.end());
```

Comment: Yes,but what about the list versions(list.remove/list.remove_if) of the remove and remove_if algorithms?

Comment: @Eric, you should rephrase your question. Remove and remove_if *algorigthms* are the free functions `remove` and `remove_if` implemented in `<algorithms>`, while `list::remove` and `list::remove_if` are member methods.

Answer (score -2):

Destructor will be always called when removing an item, no matter what method/function you use.

Comment: I did not upvote, but the downvote is probably due to the fact that neither `std::remove` nor `std::remove_if` algorithms do actually *remove* anything from containers. They only reorder the unwanted elements to the end of the sequence and return an iterator so that it is easy to actually *remove* those elements calling the `erase` method of the specific container

Answer (score -3):

Quite simply std::remove uses a value to determine if an element is to be "removed" whilst std::remove_if uses a predicate function.