# Does std::remove keep the removed elements around or could they be overwritten?

Tags: c++, remove-if

```
int main() {
    std::vector<bool> v(10, false);
    v[0] = true;
    v[1] = true;
    auto end_it = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), true);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

From [difference between erase and remove/remove_if algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031923/difference-between-erase-and-remove-remove-if-algorithms), my understanding is that all the elements in `v` that are `true` will be shifted to the end of `v`, but when I print the above it prints all `false`, so it appears my interpretation of the linked answer is not correct.

Is what happens from `end_it` to `v.end()` defined behavior?

Comment: Try `v[8] = true; v[9] = true;` and take a look.

Comment: @康桓瑋 When I do that, it prints the same as if `remove` wasn't called. Though I'm not sure how this answers my question?

Comment: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is pretty clear about it: *Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values.*

Comment: @Evg Does that contract the answers in the linked post? By "move" those answers seem to imply that the "removed" elements still remain, and that they're just in the latter segment (past the iterator returned by `remove`)

Comment: This interpretation is wrong. `std::remove` shifts elements that are *not to be removed* to the beginning of the container. What happens to elements that are to be removed, is not specified. What you're talking about is `std::stable_partition`, but implementing `std::remove` via `std::stable_partition` would be less efficient.

Comment: What happens is std::vector will move elements around (move semantics) which means that at the end of the vector you will now have "moved from" elements. And like any other "moved from" object they are accessible but their internal state is not specified (and depends on the move constructor implementation of the type).

Comment: @Evg with "shifts" you mean "moved" right?

Comment: @PepijnKramer "move assigned"